# accept() function returning -1 in case of IPv6

Tags: ipv6

In my program, I am trying to implement support for dual-stack operation (both IPv4 and IPv6 sockets).

In the case of IPv4, everything is working fine. But in the IPv6 case, `accept()` is returning a `-1` value (an error).

Can anyone suggest the possible reasons, and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `accept()` returns `-1`, `errno` will be set to indicate what specific error occurred. Please call `perror("accept")` for an easy way to see what the error was, and update your question with the results.

Also, please note that `accept()` must be called on a socket that has been:

- Created using the `socket()` call. (you should pass `PF_INET6` for the first argument of your socket to create an IPv6 protocol family socket)
- Bound, using `bind()` using a `struct sockaddr_in6` parameter as the 2nd parameter (with its `sin6_family` set to `AF_INET6` for IPv6 to indicate you will be binding to an IPv6 address). Remember to zero out the `sin6_zero` field first. One strategy would be to zero the entire sockaddr structure, which would set the IPv6 address to IN6ADDR_ANY, which means you would just have to set the port and the address family.
- Listening, by means of calling `listen()`

If you are still having trouble, post the code you have so far.

If I had to guess (since you haven't posted any code), I think if it works with IPv4 and gets to the point where it can `accept()` a connection, but IPv6 connection `accept()` calls return `-1`, I think it's likely that you aren't passing `accept()` a large enough `struct sockaddr` for it to work.

For example, the following code:

```
printf("sizeof(struct sockaddr_in) = %ld\n", sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
printf("sizeof(struct sockaddr_in6) = %ld\n", sizeof(struct sockaddr_in6));
```

Prints (on my system):

```
sizeof(struct sockaddr_in) = 16
sizeof(struct sockaddr_in6) = 28
```

If you are only giving `accept()` enough room to write out an IPv4 address, it will fail when it accepts an IPv6 connection. Make sure you allocate either a `struct sockaddr_in6` or a `struct sockaddr_storage`, and ensure the size argument is correct.